# React toggle visibility of clicked element

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple list of items. When I click on one item I want the text inside span dissapear, but in the rest I want to make them visible. Now when I click on any all spans dissapear. Here is a simple demo:
`link: https://codepen.io/rosy654/pen/VwaZJNb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have a single value called `visible` in the state of your `Example` component and your `handleClick` funciton updates that value independently of the element clicked. (You're using the same function and same state value for both spans.)

This can easily be solved in two ways:

1. Creating a new component (example: `SpanItem`) which only contains the span and the state of that span. You're `Example` component doesn't need any state in that case and can just render the `SpanItem` component multiple times.

```
const SpanItem = ({ label }) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setVisible(!visible);
  }
  return <li onClick={handleClick}>{label} <span className={!visible && 'hide'}>Visible</span></li>
}
```

```
const Example = () => (
  <div>
    <ul>
      <SpanItem label="First Item">
      <SpanItem label="Second Item">
     </ul>
   </div>
);
```

2. You could refactor your usage of the state in the `Example` component and save one visible value per item:

```
const Example = () => {
  const defaultVisibillity = true;
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState({});
  
  const isVisible = (id) => visible[id] || defaultVisibillity;

  const handleClick = (id) => () => {
    setVisible({
      ...visible
      [id]: !isVisible(id)
    })
  }
   
    return (
        <div>
        <ul>
          <li id={1} onClick={handleClick(1)}>First Item <span className={!isVisible(1) && 'hide'}>Visible</span></li>                       <li id={2} onClick={handleClick(2)}>Second Item <span className={!isVisible(2) && 'hide'}>Visible</span></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Fantastic example.  Really well put, great example.  Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 1):

You are using same `visible` flag/state for both the `span` items. Hence either both will be **hidden** or **shown** at the same time when user clicks any one item,

- Either use different states like `visible1`/`visible2` and use them respectively
- Or keep the ids to `span` element and change code as below inside `handleClick`

```
const el = document.getElementById(e.currentTarget.id);
el.style.visibility = "hidden"; // or "visible" accordingly
```